# Marshaling unmanaged pointer from hooked function to managed object and calling its member functions using managed wrapper class

Tags: c#, c++, hook, marshalling, wrapper

I have hooked QtGui4.dll's unmanaged function `QPainter::drawTextItem(const QPointF &p, const QTextItem &ti);` using EasyHook in C#.  I have wrapped the `QPointF` and `QTextItem` classes into managed structs and can get the data from these parameters by marshaling them.  However, I would like to call member functions of the unmanaged `QPainter` class using managed code, so I am trying to wrap the `QPainter` class into a managed class.  I have access to the unmanaged code for testing purposes, but will not have access to it in production.  I have looked at the memory layout of the unmanaged classes `QPainter` and `QPaintDevice`.  The `QPainter` class is just a single pointer and the `QPaintDevice` class is just two pointers (one for the virtual function table).  I tried following the techniques in **[this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2008/12/08/inheriting-from-a-native-c-class-in-c.aspx)**, but when I call the wrapped `QPainter::device()` method just to see if I can get a pointer, my target (unmanaged, hooked) application crashes with either an access violation error (`Access violation reading location 0x00000078`) or an argument exception error (`EEArgumentException at memory location 0x003786f4`), depending on whether my wrapped `QPainter` class uses a sequential layout or not, respectively.  I don’t expect someone to correct all the source code, but I was hoping if someone could point out some of the mistakes I am making in my approach.  By the way, this is the first time I've ever posted a question on Stack Overflow because I usually find the answers to my problems from one or more existing questions.  I apologize for the long question, but I tried to simplify the problem as much as possible without leaving out potentially relevant information.  Thanks in advance for your help.

**Memory Dump:**

```
class QPainter (size = 4):
  (0) d_ptr

class QPaintDevice (size = 8):
  (0) {vfptr}
  (4) painters
```

**Unmanaged Code (qpainter.h):**

```
class QPainter
{
    QPainter();
    explicit QPainter(QPaintDevice *);
    ~QPainter();

    QPaintDevice *device() const; // trying to call this function

    void drawTextItem(const QPointF &p, const QTextItem &ti); // hooked function

    // class has additional functions, but left out for brevity
}
```

**Managed Hook (hook.cs):**

```
[DllImport("QtGui4.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true,
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.ThisCall,
    EntryPoint = "?drawTextItem@QPainter@@QAEXABVQPointF@@ABVQTextItem@@@Z")]
public static extern void QPainter_drawTextItem(IntPtr obj, IntPtr pt, IntPtr ti);

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.ThisCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,
    SetLastError = true)]
delegate void D_QPainter_drawTextItem(IntPtr obj, IntPtr pt, IntPtr ti);

static unsafe void QPainter_drawTextItem_Hooked(IntPtr obj, IntPtr pt, IntPtr ti)
{
    QTextItem qti = (QTextItem)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ti, typeof(QTextItem));
    QPointF qpt = (QPointF)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pt, typeof(QPointF));
    QPainter painter = (QPainter)Marshal.PtrToStructure(obj, typeof(QPainter));

    __QPaintDevice* pd = painter.device(); // ERROR

    QPainter_drawTextItem(obj, pt, ti);
}
```

**Managed Wrapper (wrap.cs):**

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size=8)]
public unsafe struct __QPaintDevice
{
    public IntPtr *vfptr;
    public IntPtr painters;
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size=4)]
public unsafe struct __QPainter
{
    public IntPtr d_ptr;
};

// When the following line is included, I get this error:
//     Access violation reading location 0x00000078.
// When the following line is excluded, I get this error:
//     EEArgumentException at memory location 0x003786f4.

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] // is this useful?
public unsafe class QPainter : IDisposable
{
    private __QPainter* _this;
    private __QPaintDevice* _pd;

    [DllImport("QtGui4.dll", EntryPoint = "??0QPainter@@QAE@XZ",
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.ThisCall)]
    private static extern int _QPainter_Constructor(__QPainter* ths);

    [DllImport("QtGui4.dll",
        EntryPoint = "??0QPainter@@QAE@PAVQPaintDevice@@@Z",
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.ThisCall)]
    private static extern int _QPainter_Constructor(__QPainter* ths,
        __QPaintDevice* pd);

    [DllImport("QtGui4.dll", EntryPoint = "??1QPainter@@QAE@XZ",
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.ThisCall)]
    private static extern int _QPainter_Destructor(__QPainter* ths);

    [DllImport("QtGui4.dll",
        EntryPoint = "?device@QPainter@@QBEPAVQPaintDevice@@XZ",
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.ThisCall)]
    private static extern __QPaintDevice* _device(__QPainter* ths);

    public QPainter()
    {
        _this = (__QPainter*)Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(__QPainter));
        _QPainter_Constructor(_this);
    }

    public QPainter(__QPaintDevice* pd)
    {
        _this = (__QPainter*)Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(__QPainter));
        _pd = (__QPaintDevice*)Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(__QPaintDevice));
        _QPainter_Constructor(_this, pd);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _QPainter_Destructor(_this);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)_this);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)_pd);
        _this = null;
        _pd = null;
    }

    public __QPaintDevice* device()
    {
        return _device(_this);
    }
};
```